# Lucene, Indexing and searching currency

Tags: lucene

Is it possible to index and search a value based on currency. e.g. a user should be able to index a price in US dollar, or pound or rupees.

When a user search based on us dollar it should show only item that was index based on us dollar

Answer (score 1):

I would store both a numeric value (`IntField`, perhaps), and a currency field.  When searching, you could easily filter results for a particular currency type, along the lines of

```
+currency:usd +amount:[* TO 100]
```

for 100 or less US dollars, or

```
+currency:gbp +amount:[* TO 100]
```

for 100 or less GB pounds.

Another option, if you are inclined toward using Solr, it has a specific [CurrencyField](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CurrencyField), which should handle it for you nicely.